# "Fetch as Google" renders any link as the home page in a single page application built using Angular 2

Tags: seo, google-search-console, single-page-application, render

I have Angular 2 app (SPA) running on (let's say) www.example.com.

In Google Search Console when I run fetch as Google I have the following result:

- www.example.com - renders correctly
- www.example.com/**user-profile** - renders as www.example.com page **NOT as expected user-profile page**

What do I need to do to get this page rendering properly for Googlebot?

Comment: What happens if you has a user paste that profile URL into a newly opened web browser?

Comment: When accessing URL via browser, each link is rendered correctly, but it seems that Google sees just index page.

Answer (score -1):

If Google is unable to render your Javascript, then you either need to present a static version or alter the code. You can self host images or work with a product like [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/).

Comment: Well google is able to render the default route correctly. It seems that only the other routes are the problem.

Comment: Googlebot usually does a good job of rendering client side stuff as long as it happens onload.   I'm not familiar enough with Anguar to diagnose this issue, but it shouldn't require pre-rendered static.

Comment: Google won't waste resources if it doesn't have to. Static renderings presented to the engine speed things immensely and help dynamically generated sites rank. That's why prerendering products exist. How does Google behave when you use the IP address in place of a domain name? 1.1.1.1/usernameprofile - it may be a resolution issue.